# can't create a trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

i'm trying to create a trigger but there is an error somewhere and since i'm new at this i can't solve it...

So basically i have two tables:

```
students(stud_num:INT, grade_avg :real)

grading(stud_num:INT, classe:char(5), grade:int)
```

in students `stud_num` is the primary key, and in grading it references the table students..

What my professor wants is for me to create a trigger that every time we insert a grade in grading, the `grade_avg` is updated in students.

---

This is what i have so far:

> DELIMITER %%
>
> CREATE TRIGGER something
>
> AFTER INSERT ON grading
>
> FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
>
> @stud_num=new.stud_num;
>
> UPDATE students
>
> SET grade_avg=(SELECT AVG(grade) FROM grading WHERE stud_num=@stud_num);
>
> END;
>
> %%

Can someone please help me?

Comment: And the error message is....

Comment: according to mysql its a syntax error in '@stud_num=new.stud_num;'

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the way you use the user-defined variable, and you don't actually need it, so you can just skip that by using `new.stud_num` in place of `@stud_num`.

You should also restrict your update statement to only update the row for the relevant student, rather than all rows.

```
DELIMITER %%

CREATE TRIGGER something

AFTER INSERT ON grading

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

UPDATE students
SET grade_avg=(
  SELECT AVG(grade) 
  FROM grading 
  WHERE stud_num=new.stud_num
)
WHERE stud_num=new.stud_num;

END;

%%

DELIMITER ;
```